# In MySQL how best to get a recordset with multiple children

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a table that represents events, with a primary `event_ID` key. Data might be `event_name`, `event_location`, `event_date`.

Then I have a table that represents attendees, with a primary `attendee_ID` key. Data might be `first_name`, `last_name`, `contact_number`

I have a link table which uses the `event_ID` and `attendee_ID` as foreign keys.

Now I need to query this. I want to return a record set of events between two given dates. I also need to look up the attendees of each event.

I'll be using PHP to map these records to an object. What I'll be expecting is something like:

```
array(
    // Multiple `events`
    array(
        'event_ID' => 1,
        'event_location' => 'London',
        'event_start' => '2014-11-27',
        'attendees' => array(
            // multiple `attendees`
            array(
                'attendee_ID' => 1,
                'first_name' => 'John'
                'last_name' => 'Smith',
                'contact_number' => '0207 123 1234',
            ),
            ...
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

I have tried Googling this, but cannot think of how to express what I need to achieve in a search term. I guess I need to Query heirachical data.

What I don't want to do is get a record set of events, then iterate through them making more DB calls to populate the attendees, as this seems horribly inefficient.

Another idea I was think of was to get all event records, then query for the link table, collate the attendee IDs and query the attendee table for any that match the meetings and use PHP code to re-associate them with my event object I built from the recordset.

Is there a more elegant, best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: To find a good query and db structure you have to first think over the use case. How many records you want to be able to handle in future?  Do you have a known upper limit of records? Do you need fast queries for reading or fast queries for inserting/updating? Would it be possible to cache results instead querying and recreating the structure over and over again?

Comment: user3510504 you can use simple join and fetch result to array. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a column on `attendees` table for specifying which event user attended. This is called `attended_event_ID`. By using this, you can do that with following;

```
<?php

  $query =  "SELECT e.event_ID, e.event_location, e.event_start,
             a.attendee_ID, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.contact_number, a.attended_event_ID
             FROM events e
             LEFT JOIN attendees a ON a.attended_event_ID = e.event_ID
             ORDER BY e.event_ID";
  $result = $db->query($query);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $events[$row["event_ID"]]["event_ID"] = $row["event_ID"];
    $events[$row["event_ID"]]["event_location"] = $row["event_location"];
    $events[$row["event_ID"]]["event_start"] = $row["event_start"];
    $events[$row["event_ID"]]["attendees"][] = array(
                                                    "attendee_ID" => $row["attendee_ID"],
                                                    "first_name" => $row["first_name"],
                                                    "last_name" => $row["last_name"],
                                                    "contact_number" => $row["contact_number"]
                                                );
  }        

?>
```

Comment: You have to change your $events["event_ID"] as $events[$row["event_ID"]]. Then only we can store multiple. Otherwise this won't work. Leftjoin may yield more tha one records that time data duplication problem will occur. Also change the index of this $events["attendees".$row["event_ID"]] to avoid problems

Comment: @Sundar thanks for your suggestion. I have forgotten to add id. I have refactored my code a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    event . *,
    CONCAT('[',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"name":"',
                        attendees.name,
                        '", id:"',
                        attendees.id,
                        '"}')),
            ']') attendees
FROM
    `event`
        LEFT JOIN
    attendees ON attendees.event = event.id
GROUP BY event.id
```

Will return your results in the following format

```
1   event2  [{"name":"name-1-1", id:"6142"},{"name":"name-1-1", id:"2048"},{"name":"name-1-1", id:"1"},{"name":"name-1-1", id:"4095"}]
2   event3  [{"name":"name-2-2", id:"2"},{"name":"name-2-2", id:"4096"},{"name":"name-2-2", id:"6143"},{"name":"name-2-2", id:"2049"}]
3   event4  [{"name":"name-3-3", id:"6144"},{"name":"name-3-3", id:"2050"},{"name":"name-3-3", id:"3"},{"name":"name-3-3", id:"4097"}]
4   event5  [{"name":"name-4-4", id:"4"},{"name":"name-4-4", id:"4098"},{"name":"name-4-4", id:"6145"},{"name":"name-4-4", id:"2051"}]
5   event6  [{"name":"name-5-5", id:"6146"},{"name":"name-5-5", id:"2052"},{"name":"name-5-5", id:"5"},{"name":"name-5-5", id:"4099"}]
6   event7  [{"name":"name-6-6", id:"6"},{"name":"name-6-6", id:"4100"},{"name":"name-6-6", id:"6147"},{"name":"name-6-6", id:"2053"}]
```

The attendees result is a valid JSON and can be decoded using JSON_DECODE.

Make sure you have indexes This works in 0.047 seconds on 2000+ events and 8000+ attendees

Comment: You should mention that it has to be ensured that `name` does not contain a char that would make the json invalid.

Comment: That's a different question. You should always be carefull what you insert in your DB. Escape your strings before making your inserts. That way, the characters that could brake your JSON (quotes mostly) are already escaped when you retrieve them.

Comment: Using values for a query (e.g. inserting)  the values may escaped according to the technique how the values are _inserted_ to the query, this by be direct inserting into the query itself, or by passing as value to the query engine e.g. using prepared statements. But in the end they are stored unescaped in the database. You may add additional escaping but that will lead to more problems. So when you retrieve them they are not escaped.

Comment: Well, in that case there is no real solution. All kind of mysql escapes will trigger errors depending on the case. All concat styles will give errors depending on the use cases. (separation by comma will create issues if you have commas in your records, etc). There is no perfect way for retrieving this perfectly. You need to adjust to your needs and fix it accordingly.

Comment: Sure, but as the answer does not mention those problems, it indicates that it does not suffer from escaping problems, thats why I said that it should be mentioned. So that the OP or others reading your solution are award of that.